# Not removing the selected datagirdview row

Tags: c#, datagridview, windows-forms-designer

I want to remove the selected row from the datagridview with the delete button, but the row that I choose will not be deleted and the first row
The data grid is deleted. Thank you if you give advice

These are the button code :

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (dgcontact.CurrentRow != null)
    {
        if (MessageBox.Show("...", "...", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            int personID = Convert.ToInt32(dgcontact.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString());
            repository.delete(personID);
        }
    }
}
```

And this is a method of deletion :

```
public bool delete(int personID)
{
    string connectionstring = "data source=.;initial catalog=person;integrated security=true";
    string query = "delete from tperson where personID=@personID";
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionstring);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@personID", personID);
    conn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();
    return true;
}
```

Comment: There is a difference between CurrentRow and SelectedRow. Do you have cursor on the same row as the selected one?

Comment: Yes, but when I select the delete button, instead of deleting the same row, the first row that is not selected is deleted

Comment: Did you debugged it? Was `personID` selected correctly? So that you know was the problem with deleting function or with the selection.

Comment: Yes, I did debugging. I chose the row, but when I click the delete button, the first row appears in the personID

Comment: So, the deletion method is not needed here, I suppose. Regarding selection I suggest you to try `dgcontact.SelectedRows`. It will give you a list that you can go through and delete each element of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

don't use CurrentRow, just iterate over SelectedCells

```
using System.Linq;

if (MessageBox.Show("...", "...", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.Yes)
{
int selectedPersonId = dgcontact.SelectedCells.Cast<DataGridViewCell>()
                .Where(cell => cell.OwningColumn.Index.Equals(1))
                .Select(cell => Convert.ToInt32(cell.Value)).First();
repository.delete(selectedPersonId);
}
```